# React native app closes by itself when calling signInWithPhoneNumber() method of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I am working on`React-native` application.

I am supposed to do `Phone authentication` in my app, when I click the button which sends the `OTP` to phone, The app `closes` by itself even not printing any erros.

Here is my Code =>

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,TextInput,Button,TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import firebase from './setupFirebase';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      code:'',
      confirm:null,
      firebase:firebase
    }
  }

  async signInWithPhoneNumber(number){
    try{
    console.log('SignIn Button Clicked')
    let {firebase} = this.state;
    const {auth} = firebase()
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number)
    console.log(confirmation)
    this.setState({
      confirm:confirmation
    },console.log('OTP send'))
  }
  catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
  }

  async confirmCode(){
    try{
      console.log('Checked into confirmCode method')
      const {confirm,code} = this.state;
      await confirm.confirm(code)
    }
    catch(err){
      alert(err);
    }
  };

  render(){

    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'white',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        { !this.state.confirm &&        
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.signInWithPhoneNumber('+91xxxxxxxxxx')}>          
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',padding:20}}>            
                <Text style={{color:'white'}}>SigIn</Text>            
            </View>        
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        }
        {
          this.state.confirm &&
          <>
          <TextInput placeholder='Enter OTP' value={this.state.code} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({code:text})} />      
          <Button onPress={() => this.confirmCode()} title='Confirm OTP'></Button>    
          </>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I dont know what is the error...

My firebase configurations are correct..
I have configured the android also ehich have been given in the document, i tried to print firebase instance before initializeApp() it prints as `1`.

I think this is happens bcoz android config. how to get rid out of that?

```
let firebaseConfig = {
    //configs....
}

console.log(`FIREBASE INSTANCE => ${firebase.apps.length}`) 
// prints => FIREBASE INSTANCE => 1

if(!firebase.apps.length){
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

console.log(`FIREBASE INSTANCE => ${firebase.apps.length}`) 
// prints => FIREBASE INSTANCE => 1
```

Here is my ***Logcat***

```
11-30 11:05:09.855  4107  4164 I ReactNativeJS: SignIn Button Clicked
11-30 11:05:09.889  8871 11216 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24094239 , only wrote 24094080
11-30 11:05:09.890  4107  4165 D Auth    : addAuthStateListener
11-30 11:05:09.892  4107  4165 D Auth    : addIdTokenListener
11-30 11:05:09.892  4107  4165 D Auth    : signInWithPhoneNumber
11-30 11:05:09.894  4107  4107 D Auth    : addAuthStateListener:eventBody { NativeMap: {"appName":"[DEFAULT]"} }
11-30 11:05:13.085  8871  8905 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 24398821 , only wrote 24247440
11-30 11:05:13.833 10705 10774 W SystemServiceRegistry: No service published for: persistent_data_block
11-30 11:05:14.122  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRPKEY_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.123  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRSKEY_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.123  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRCERT_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.123  1481  1481 I keystore: del CACERT_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.132  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received add_rng_entropy
11-30 11:05:14.133  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 36 msg size 40
11-30 11:05:14.135  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 4 byte response
11-30 11:05:14.140  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received generate_key
11-30 11:05:14.142  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 49 msg size 53
11-30 11:05:14.147  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 408 byte response
11-30 11:05:14.162  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received get_key_characteristics
11-30 11:05:14.163  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 283 msg size 287
11-30 11:05:14.163  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 137 byte response
11-30 11:05:14.164  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received export_key
11-30 11:05:14.164  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 287 msg size 291
11-30 11:05:14.165  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 99 byte response
11-30 11:05:14.170  1481  1481 E keystore_att_id: package manager request for key attestation ID failed with: 
11-30 11:05:14.170  1481  1481 E keystore: failed to gather attestation_id
11-30 11:05:14.171  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRPKEY_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.173  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRSKEY_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.173  1481  1481 I keystore: del USRCERT_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:14.174  1481  1481 I keystore: del CACERT_unstable.c7202ece89390c490b1b94d5b71225e1.7549987102814076746 10013
11-30 11:05:15.080  8917  8931 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-30 11:05:15.081  8917  8931 W android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
11-30 11:05:15.253  4107  4114 I zygote  : Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=78KB
11-30 11:05:15.263  4107  4114 I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=98KB, data=54KB
11-30 11:05:15.877  4107  4107 E zza     : Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
11-30 11:05:15.904  8917  9468 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.firebase.auth.internal.ACTION_SHOW_RECAPTCHA pkg=com.myntraduplicate cmp=com.myntraduplicate/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity (has extras)} from uid 10083
11-30 11:05:16.205  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received get_key_characteristics
11-30 11:05:16.205  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 210 msg size 214
11-30 11:05:16.205  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 153 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.243  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received get_key_characteristics
11-30 11:05:16.243  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 210 msg size 214
11-30 11:05:16.243  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 153 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.244  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received add_rng_entropy
11-30 11:05:16.244  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 16 msg size 20
11-30 11:05:16.245  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 4 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.251  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received begin
11-30 11:05:16.251  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 246 msg size 250
11-30 11:05:16.252  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 48 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received update
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 34 msg size 38
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 34 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Device received finish
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 28 msg size 32
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 36 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: here finish at 619 output data length 16
11-30 11:05:16.271  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: OK here finish at 627
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received get_key_characteristics
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 210 msg size 214
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 153 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received begin
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 270 msg size 274
11-30 11:05:16.275  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 24 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received update
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 50 msg size 54
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 34 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Device received finish
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 28 msg size 32
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 20 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: here finish at 619 output data length 0
11-30 11:05:16.276  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: OK here finish at 627
11-30 11:05:16.296  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received get_key_characteristics
11-30 11:05:16.296  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 210 msg size 214
11-30 11:05:16.296  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 153 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.301  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received begin
11-30 11:05:16.301  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 270 msg size 274
11-30 11:05:16.301  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 24 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.302  1344  1344 D TrustyKeymaster: Device received update
11-30 11:05:16.303  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 308 msg size 312
11-30 11:05:16.303  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 292 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.304  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Device received finish
11-30 11:05:16.304  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: calling trusty_keymaster_call insize 28 msg size 32
11-30 11:05:16.304  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: Received 20 byte response
11-30 11:05:16.304  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: here finish at 619 output data length 0
11-30 11:05:16.304  1344  1344 E TrustyKeymaster: OK here finish at 627
11-30 11:05:16.394  4107  4107 I zzip    : Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
11-30 11:05:16.603  1394  1440 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 16683008
11-30 11:05:16.772  1404  1906 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe5b794c0, tid 1906
11-30 11:05:16.794  1394  1440 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 16683008
11-30 11:05:16.871  1394  1440 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 16683008
11-30 11:05:17.011  4107  4153 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe01a9660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe809ba10)
11-30 11:05:17.264  8917  8939 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.myntraduplicate/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity: +1s183ms
```

Comment: If you are running on android, try running adb logcat and see if it is giving you any error. For ios, use xcode for the same.

Comment: I have figured out my firebase is already initialized with some other value?? how to solve that